# In slave mongoDB, when I run "show dbs" command I am getting this error

Tags: mongodb

In slave mongoDB, when I run "show dbs" command I am getting this error:

```
E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listDatabases failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "unable to open cursor at URI statistics:table:collection-2-6982414143487404550. reason: No such file or directory",
    "code" : 43,
    "codeName" : "CursorNotFound"
} :
```